# New Everyplay SDK alert on beta adhoc build in Unity3D for iOS

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, everyplay

I have a Unity3d game with Everyplay integration. It is NOT live on iOS. The iTunes ID corresponds to the non-live version of the application.

When a user (adhoc test user) tries to share a video via Everyplay, they get an alert

> "NEW IOS Everyplay SDK is available for download."

This is not what I expect in production settings.

1. Our game is using the latest Everyplay Unity3d SDK from the Unity3d asset store. Is the Unity SDK due for an update?
2. Why does Everyplay show an alert to a test-user instead of emailing/alerting developer?
3. I assume Everyplay auto-detects whether an application is live or not, correct? Once my application is live, users will not see this alert. Can anyone please confirm?

Comment: Can you check the iOS console output when running the app and check the SDK version? The Everyplay SDK does automatically detect if the app is live or not, so it will not show the alert to real users.

Comment: Yes, ios sdk version is not latest. But this is the latest version of unity sdk. Probably unity sdk is due an update. Good to confirm that it'll not show alert to real users. Ideally it should not even show alert to test user in order to simulate pre production testing. Thanks for the confirmation.